# Getting a MongoDB document's field value into a variable

Tags: mongodb, shell, find

I am using mongo's shell and want to do what is basically equivalent to "SQL's select col INTO var" and then use the value of var to look up other rows in the same table or others (Joins). For example, in PL/SQL I will declare a variable called V_Dno. I also have a table called Emp(EID, Name, Sal, Dno). I can access the value of Dno for employee 100 as, "Select Dno into V_Dno from Emp where EID = 100). In MongoDB, when I find the needed employee (using its _id), I end up with a document and not a value (a field). In a sense, I get equivalent to the entire row in SQL and not just a column. I am doing the following to find the given emp:

```
VAR V_Dno = db.emp.find ({Eid : 100}, {Dno : 1});
```

The reason I want to do this to traverse from one document into the other using the value of a field. I know I can do it using the DBRef, but I wanted to see if I could tie documents together using this method. 
Can someone please shed some light on this?
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Two clarification points. (1) since I am using “_id” to look up the document, boht **find()** and **findOne()** do the same thing, and (2) since I will be using the dot notation to extract the Dno field, I really do not need to use {dno : 1}.  I tested the following and worked just fine.  
`var V_Dno = db.emp.find({Eid : 100}).Dno;  
V_Dno  
15`  
Do you agree?  
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`find` returns a cursor that lets you iterate over the matching documents.  In this case you'd want to use `findOne` instead as it directly returns the first matching doc, and then use dot notation to access the single field.

```
var V_Dno = db.emp.findOne({Eid : 100}, {Dno : 1}).Dno;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your query as a starting point:

```
var vdno = db.emp.findOne({Eid: 100, Dno :1})
```

This returns a document from the emp collection where the Eid = 100 and the Dno = 1. Now that I have this document in the vdno variable I can "join" it to another collection. Lets say you have a Department collection, a document in the department collection has a manual reference to the _id field in the emp collection. You can use the following to filter results from the department collection based on the value in your variable.

```
db.department.find({"employee._id":vdno._id})
```